# Do I need a UK Transit Visa to go back to Peru when I change of Airports in the UK?

Tags: uk, transit, airports, transit-visas, peru

I'm from Peru and I'm going to The Netherlands in the beginning of 2017.
I fly back on February 28th. My flight is the next:
Amsterdam - London Heathrow - London Gatwick - Lima.
The time between arriving in the UK and leaving again is 16 hours. (I arrive Feb 28 at 10p.m. and leave again at Mar 1 at 2p.m.)

I want to know if I need a Transit Visa to change airports in London, or if i can go back home without a visa. Both flights are with British Airways.

All the information I find on the internet is very confusing and doesn't give me a clear answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm have a Peruvian nationality, I'm from Peru

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it doesn't give a clear answer on my specific situation..

Comment: As far as I can see, it answers your question. [You need a transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/peru/transit/yes), unless you qualify for one of the exemptions. But nothing you've shown in this post suggests that you qualify.

Comment: I can travel to Schengen countries (e.g. The Netherlands) without needing a visa. When I go back to Peru, I'm changing of airport in the UK, so that makes that I need a transit visa?

Comment: Yes. It is very simple and clear. You need the visa to change airports in the UK. The only thing not clear is that you seem to be unwilling to accept it.

Comment: @GerardZwaan You Need an airside transit visa for the UK. The UK and Schengen have separate visa policies. If you had an Irish, Australian, New Zealander, American or Canadian visa/residence permit, or a Schengen long-stay visa or residence permit, that would be a different story